# Why does Python look for __members__ rather than the requested field?

Tags: python, getattr

I have a class that defines its own `__getattr__()` in order to interact with an XML tree instantiated objects contain. This hides the XML structure from the user and allows him to set tag values, etc. as if they were normal fields on the object and works fine for all fields except for one: The one named `field`. Here's how it looks:

```
>>> q = MyQuery()
>>> q.file = "database"
>>> print(q)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<requestCollection xmlns="http://dwd.de/sky">
  <read>
    <select>
      <referenceDate>
        <value></value>
      </referenceDate>
    </select>
    <transfer>
      <file name="my file"/>
    </transfer>
  </read>
</requestCollection>
>>> q.file
```

That works fine, the side effects that should happen do so. But if I try to set the field `field`, I get a string that the method shouldn't be returning. For clarity, this is a simplified version of my `__getattr__`:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    logging.info("Looking up value for key {}.".format(key))
    if key == "something"
        return self.method_with_side_effect(key)
    if key in field_list:
        logging.info("Key is in the field list.")
        return self.other_method_with_side_effects(key)
```

`ensemble_member` and `field` are both in `field_list`. Check this out:

```
>>> q = MyQuery()
>>> q.ensemble_member
Looking up value for key __members__.
Looking up value for key __methods__.
Looking up value for key ensemble_member.
Key is in the field list.
... Side effects ...
>>> q.field
'station'
Looking up value for key __members__.
Looking up value for key __methods__.
```

The behavior for `ensemble_member` is correct, for `field` it's totally incorrect. Why is that?

I have no methods nor class / object members named `field`.

Another interesting thing is, if I put this on the first line of `__getattr__`:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    if key == "field":
        raise ValueError
```

The following still happens:

```
>>> q = MyQuery()
>>> q.field
'station'
Looking up value for key __members__.
Looking up value for key __methods__.
```

What's going on?

Comment: Please post a small runnable example that demonstrates the problem. Also, which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Are you calling `dir(q)` somewhere?

Comment: I'm not calling dir(q) anywhere, although I just tried it out and "field" is in there. I'm not sure how it got there though.

Comment: I took a quick look; I think you should try to isolate the problem by removing code irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it - the offending code was, in the end, these lines:

```
class SkyQuery(object):
    _unique_fields = ["parameter",
                      "ensemble",
                      "forecast",
                      "station"]
    _field_tag_values = [field + "_value" for field in _unique_fields]
```

Naming the temporary variable "field" in my list comprehension was causing the problem. Python was retaining it after I was done. This behavior is consistent, I just wasn't expecting it.

I see three solutions here (the third was suggested by user4815162342). I implemented the third.

1. Rename the temporary variable to `x` rather than `field`. Then I still have `x` as a temporary variable floating around in my code, but because no members should be called `x` it doesn't bother me.
2. Call `del(field)` to delete the field. I don't like calling `del()` and I thought it would clutter up my code, but it would work if I really needed to be able to access that variable later on.
3. replace the list comprehension with a generator expression `list(field + "_value" for field in _unique_fields)` which does not share this problem

Comment: 3. replace the list comprehension with a generator expression `list(field + "_value" for field in _unique_fields)` which does not share this problem